# Nothing is happening on clicking Submit in flask (FlaskForm)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

This is my code (i changed it to check f the form is validating or not ):

views function:

```
@app.route('/modi',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def IssMed():
    form = medis()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Ok")
        redirect(url_for('ViewMedicine'))
    return render_template('issuemedicine.html',form=form)
```

my forms.py:

```
class medis(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Medicine Name",validators=[Optional()])
    qty = IntegerField("Quantity",validators=[Optional()])
    submit = SubmitField('Issue')
```

my html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">

  {{form.name.label}} {{form.name()}}
  {{form.qty.label()}} {{form.qty()}}
  {{form.submit()}}

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

i can't determine where i made the mistake please help me out :(

Comment: You might be getting tripped up by the CSRF (cross-site request forgery) protection that comes with flask_wtf. Have you seen https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html ?

Comment: Thank you..! i forgot to put the hidden tag and i am wondering for hours where i made the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

You aren't seeing any errors because you aren't printing any errors. It might make sense to print a list of errors if the form hasn't submitted. There are a variety of ways you can do that, such as printing errors on each field, or printing a list of errors at the top of the form:

```
{% for error_field, error_list in form.errors.items() %}
   <p>Errors on field: {{error_field}}</p>
   <ul>
        {% for error in error_list %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Second, the reason is most likely that you're missing a csrf token. Add this to your form:

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

For more details, check out the [Form Validation docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/).